# Hardware accelerated css3 transitions for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, hardware-acceleration

I don't think my translate3d is forcing hardware acceleration (of top / bottom positioning). What am I missing?

```
.image {
        background:yellow;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, top, bottom;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post more complete code?

Answer (score 0):

So, the animation of the transition is slower/choppier than you'd like? I'm guessing from the class name `image` that the problem might just be the fact that it's an image, even with hardware acceleration kicking in; my team at work has struggled with this sometimes in doing UI simulations/demos on iOS. You might try, just as a test, replacing the image with an identically-sized `div` and seeing if it moves more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class which I added to all elements that triggered choppy animations. The animations was not choppy on iPad 2, but was making all kinds of performance issues on the iPad Retina.

```
.gpu-rendered {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```